# ACF unable to use user field

Tags: customization, advanced-custom-fields

I am totally new to wordpress and acf and I'm trying to use a user field in a post to show the author of the post. I tried to programatically add the post author id as a meta attribute in the wp_postmeta table like this:

```
update_field('video_author', get_current_user_id(), $post_id);
```

The post author, however, is not shown:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Also when I click the user field no users are listed. I presume acf looks for users in either "wp_users" or "users" table, both of which contain records. However, this is shown:

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If this is a regular post, the author is already saved in the database. Even if you create the post programatically, if that script is triggered by the logged in user, that user will be the post's author.

Comment: @NightHawk But how to I show this user in my post edit page?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ACF then you don't need to update field manually. Field will be updated when you update the post.

And To retrieve this field use :

```
get_field( 'video_author', $post_id );
```

For User field, make sure you have selected Field Type -> User in ACF.

Comment: I need to create a post programatically (with wp_insert_post) and then to the newly creted post - set it's "video_author" field to the current logged user's id, this is my custom logic.

Comment: Ok, In that case you can use update_field